# Drupal - How to change input format for comments?

Tags: drupal, drupal-comments, drupal-input-format

This issue irritates me much.
Somehow after installing wysiwig editor my comment body form turned into rich.. bla bla area.
I do not want this but I can not find the place where to turn back comment input format to the plain text (or filtered format).
I know how to change filter options for different content types but turning back comments to the simple format simply drives me crazy!
Please help - where is this configuration place for comments?

Comment: If you are logged in as User 1, WYSIWYGs tend to attach themselves to any textbox.

Comment: Yes, but I tested it also on other test accounts. I can disable wysiwig by role but is not enought as I want specific input format settings for comments only.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Better Formats](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_formats) will do the trick. Some more details about this module (from its project page):

> Better formats is a module to add more flexibility to Drupal's core input format system.
>
> Features
>
> - Set allowed text formats per field.
> - Set default order of text formats per field.
> - Hide format tips per role.
> - Hide more format tips link per role.
> - Hide format selection per role per entity.
> - Currently only works on Field API fields on fieldable entities implementing core style text processing. The good thing is that is most things in core and contrib.

Answer (score 10):

here:

```
admin/structure/types/manage/[contentType]/comment/fields/comment_body
```

you could also set the format, in **D7** at least ..

Comment: Hey, thanks for pointing this out. Should be ovious, but I didn't think about going there!

Comment: That works but only for switching between full html and plain text. You cannot choose filtered HTML.

Comment: **After** installing Better Formats, you can see in that path new options to choose the Text format. Core just offers switching between Plain Text or Formatted text.
Also don't be fooled: The "Default" text option doesn't save the Text Format option.. its purpose is different.